# Reading both integers and strings from multiple lines stored in a text file

Tags: c++

So my Text file is:

```
5 6
gakiwi
rpopla
apapba
plemon
eeepbp
6
apple
lemon
banana
kiwi
papaya
grape
```

Two integers in the first line represent rows and columns of a character matrix, each line next to it represent characters of the matrix. After the said number of rows(or lines, in this case 5) , there is number, which represents the no of words which would come down it.
words need to be read to another string array called dict[nWords].
I want to read all characters from character matrix into an string array, i.e charMatrix[rows];
My code is here, for some reason, it doesn't work.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("input.txt");
    if(!infile)
    cout<<"Input file cannot be opened."<<endl;

    int rows, cols, nWords;
    char ch;
    infile>>rows>>cols;
    string charMatrix[rows];
    string dict[6];

    while(infile.get() == '\n') //in order to move to the next line


    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)   
        getline(infile, charMatrix[i]);

//my code works fine until here, after I add the folowing code, nothing works fine.
    infile>>nWords;

    while(infile.get() == '\n')  //in order to move to the next line

    for(int i=0;i<nWords;i++)
        getline(infile, dict[i]);

   return 0;

}
```

Comment: *How* doesn't it work? What happens when you run your program? And how do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: `string charMatrix[rows];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their sizes denoted by a contant expression, not a variable.  The proper way to do this in C++ is `std::vector<std::string> charMatrix(rows);`

Comment: your `while` loops should probably have a semicolon immediately after them. your indentation implies you think the `for` loops are not inside the `while` loops, but they are